# Stable extensions by line bundles on Riemann surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Is there a compact Riemann surface $X$ and a line bundle $L$ of negative degree on $X$, such that for any nontrivial extension
$$ 0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow E \rightarrow L^{-1} \rightarrow 0, $$
$E$ is a stable vector bundle on $X$? Any comment and reference is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This never happens. Pick a point $p\in X$;   the exact sequence $0\rightarrow L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}(p)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_p\rightarrow 0$ gives rise to an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\xrightarrow{\ \partial \ } H^1(L^2)\longrightarrow H^1(L^2(p))\rightarrow 0$. The class
 $e:=\partial (1)$ in $H^1(L^2)\cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(L^{-1},L) $ maps to $0$ in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(L^{-1}(-p),L) $, hence it defines a nontrivial extension of $L^{-1}$ by $L$ which becomes trivial when pulled back to $L^{-1}(-p)$. This means that the extension bundle $E$ contains $L^{-1}(-p)$, hence is not stable.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the openness of stability, we know that the unstable extensions form a subvariety of Ext$^1(L^{-1},L)$ of codimension $\ge 1$. Can we expect that the subvariety has codimension $>1$ for some general Riemann surfaces? For example $g(X) > 1$.

Comment: If $X$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g>1$, I proved that there always exist stable extension bundles.@abx

Comment: Yes, I think that quite generally the subvariety of unstable extensions has high codimension. You might have a look at a paper by A. Bertram, *Moduli of rank-2 vector bundles, theta divisors, and the geometry of curves in projective space* (J. Differential Geom. 35 (1992), no. 2, 429-469). He does a detailed analysis (in a slightly different situation) of the stability of extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a (complex irreducible) curve of genus at least two. Then, for every line bundle $L$ on $C$ of negative degree, there exist extensions of $L^{-1}$ by $L$ which are stable. Furthermore, the generic extension of $L^{-1}$ by $L$ is stable if $\operatorname{deg}(L)>-(g-1)/2.$ This is discussed in Chapter 4, Friedman: *Algebraic Surfaces and Holomorphic Vector Bundles* and the case when $\operatorname{deg}(L)=-1$ is proven in **Theorem 10** of the same chapter.

Comment: The question is whether for *any* nontrivial extension the corresponding vector bundle is stable.

Comment: @abx Yes, but since OP said "Any comment and reference is welcome," I thought I would mention this reference. I couldn't point this out as a comment because of reputation. But I still believe it's relevant.